# Use a Unicode surrogate pair character in Arduino IDE

Tags: arduino-ide

I'm writing a sketch for a Wemos D1 Mini to display a web page. This works and I can get Unicode characters to display, but if I try to use ones with surrogate pairs like 🔊 I get a compile error;

```
  s += "\uD83D\uDD0A";
```

Error

> \uD83D is not a valid universal character

How can I get this character in my code?

Comment: Google the error message "\uD83D is not a valid universal character" and you fill find lots of answers.

Answer (score 1):

There is a nifty new feature in C++11 called [string literal](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/string_literal), this example shows how to use it with any single line or multi line or utf8 text. You just define starting and ending sequence, in following case `---` (starting sequence becomes `R"---(` and ending sequence `)---"`) and make sure that this sequence does not appear in encapsulated text. This is great for integrating websites into arduino projects:

```
static const char _index_html[] PROGMEM = R"---(
<html>
<head>
<link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="/favicon.png"/>
</head>
<body>
...
</body>
</html>
)---";
```

Comment: Okay, but what does that have to do with the SMP? Or anything outside ASCII for that matter?

Comment: If he had used any unicode capable editor, he could just copy/paste any unicode symbols without caring how to encode them - no need to use escaping sequences. Also this answers shows how to easily integrate mutliline HTML code into arduino project

Answer (score 0):

After some trial and error, I got it using the python style `u"\U0001F50A"` without the leading u of course

```
  s += "\U0001F50A";
```

Too bad I didn't think about googling the error msg, would have saved me some time.

Comment: Can you use pure UTF-8 characters in the source code ? It is a risk, because everything should be able to handle them. I think it should work. At least this forum can handle pure UTF-8 characters: ±10 °C, 10 µm, 1 kΩ, ¿

Comment: Actually, you can. I didn't even try that.